# Splice method doesent insert element

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have an issue where i want to add a char at a specific index in a string. Its supposed to take a http... address and add "s" at the end of http. After splice console log doesn't even print "url". What am I doing wrong?
`const url = hero.comics.collectionURI.split("").splice(5, 0, "s").join("");`

Comment: `splice` isn't chainable like that, it doesn't return the original array, but the removed elements.

Comment: A quick google on "splice() js" would show you how it works. Rely on the MDN, it's very valuable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` returns the deleted elements as an array, not the array it was called on.

```
let arr = hero.comics.collectionURI.split("");
arr.splice(5, 0, "s");
const url = arr.join("");
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i would have never figured it out :)

Comment: @VeljkoS Glad to help.